# Why does the c#(web) linq syntax is different in vb(windows) linq syntax?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

In c# web linq syntax for example

```
var sample = (from a in db.sample where a.id == id).singleordefault();
```

while in windows linq

```
dim sample = (from a in db.sample where a.id = id)
```

Because they have a different environment?.

Comment: What do you mean with web and windows? C# runs on Windows too.

Comment: What is "windows linq" and "web linq"? LINQ is the tool created for .NET, not especially for windows and not especially for web.

Comment: @Uki Both languages are independent, their architecture are different.

Comment: Have you actually checked the type of those two variables?  I would expect them to be different.  I believe that the first will be `Sample` or the like while the second will be `IEnumerable(Of Sample)`.

Comment: C# and VB.NET syntax ? Each of them has a separate compiler. They don't speak the same language but they use the same APIs and boil down to the same IL. However, the two lines you specified are not identical because of the extra `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov sorry for the term. What I mean in windows / web linq is for windows why the query is like that and in asp.net c# is different too?.

Comment: First query is c#, the second vb.net. And the won't return the same data, the first one will return only one row,the second a IEnumerable. So no, the Linq syntax is not different

Comment: @Pikoh can the vb.net adopt the c# linq?. I mean is like in my example

Comment: If your query will return zero or one match and you want that one object then call `SingleOrDefault` and if you want all the matches regardless of how many there then don't.  It's that simple.  Whether the app is C# or VB, web or Windows is COMPLETELY irrelevant.  You're trying to make this hard when it's easy.

Comment: I'm not used to VB.net, but i guess the first sentence in vb.net would be something like `dim sample = (from a in db.sample where a.id = id).SingleOrDefault();` So, the only things that change is  the `var` keyword  (in vb.net would be `Dim`) and the equal comparator (`==` in c#, `=`) in VB.net

Comment: @Pikoh so the extension `.SingleOrDefault();` can also use in vb.net?

Comment: Yes Uki...Linq is the same in both languages

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks for the informations :) +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listed approach can be classified into `LINQ` *method* syntax and *query* syntax and both are semantically identical. Some of us find query syntax is simple and easy to read while others prefer method syntax because of it's expressiveness.

Following will help you to clarify;

[Query and Method Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not both are same they have also use the same library System.Linq;

if you use below code then get only one object that satisfy your condition

```
var sample = (from a in db.sample where a.id == id).singleordefault();
```

and if you use

```
dim dm = from a in db.sample where a.id == id
```

then get whole list that match with this .

**so both query are same.**

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there are two differences here:

1. First sample is written on C# (`==` means "equals"). Second on VB.NET (`=` means equals)
2. First sample will return `Sample` or `null` (if `Sample` is a class). Second - `IEnumerable<Sample>` (C# syntax) or `IEnumerable(Of Sample)` (VB.NET syntax)